Seeking Best Practices for Authentication Setup Using Named Credentials
I'm currently working on implementing authentication using Named Credentials in my project.
I'm looking for insights into the best practices widely used in the industry to ensure comprehensive coverage of all authentication steps.
I have reviewed much queries regarding the best practice , none of them gave clarity and conclusion to me.
Any advice, tips, or recommended resources would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you in advance for your help!

Have you checked this help documents? - https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.nc_auth_protocols.htm&type=5    - https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.nc_custom_headers_basic_auth.htm&type=5

Yeah I have referred them both articles , they suggesting the types and flows of Authentications . But I am seeking , which one is generally used industrial wide and which the best one?

Don't think of the options as one is better than the others. Each have specific use cases, much like how you wouldn't use a screwdriver when you need a hammer, nor a saw when you need a drill. They each have specific purposes.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
